# Problems with an object appearing on a frame I don't want it to appear on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a total noob at AS3, roughly 1 year experience so please be lenient with me :)

I currently am making an endless runner game and I'm making the obstacles spawn using this method

```
var therespawn:RespawnObject;
var thecone:trafficcone;
var started:Boolean = false;
var dx:Number = 10;
var dy:Number = 10;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startGame);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coneCollision);

function startGame(evt:Event):void {
    if (started == false) {
        spawnHazard();
    }
}

function spawnHazard() {
    started = true;
    therespawn = new RespawnObject();
    addChild(therespawn);
    thecone = new trafficcone();
    addChild(thecone);
    therespawn.x = -50;
    therespawn.y = 310;
    thecone.x = 600;
    thecone.y = 310;
}

function collision(evt:Event):void {
    thecone.x -= 15;
    if(thecone.hitTestObject(therespawn)) {
        thecone.x = 600;
    }
}
```

Now the only way to finish the game or end it is to get hit by an obstacle which ive shown down below:

```
function coneCollision(evt:Event):void {
    if(MainChar.hitTestObject(thecone)) {
    gotoAndStop("frameFive");
    }
}
```

Everytime the highscore frame appears the cone is still spawning and despawning, why is that?
I haven't declared them as global?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem by setting started to false:

```
function coneCollision(evt:Event):void {
    if(MainChar.hitTestObject(thecone)) {
        started = false;
        gotoAndStop("frameFive");
    }
}
```

The flash timeline really only has to with the way MovieClips are visually displayed as children of the stage. Removing an object from the timeline doesn't just suddenly nullify all the code associated with that object. In other words, your ENTER_FRAME method still runs in the background even if the object is no longer a child of the Stage, regardless of the frame number for the MovieClip. If you're serious about coding you might consider investigating in Classes and Object Oriented AS3. Classes are  much nicer to work with than the Flash timeline.